# Tabs resetting after selecting drop down list in C# , ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab3"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab4"></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab5"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab6"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab7"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="#tab8"></a></li>
```

```
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">

  </div>
  <div id="tab3">


  </div>
  <div id="tab4">

  </div>
  <div id="tab5">

  </div>
  <div id="tab6">
   <table>
          <tr>
              <td style ="color: Black "><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  onselectedindexchanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                  <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem>250</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="6">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CurrentSortField="ActivityDate" CurrentSortDirection="ASC" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPreRender="GridView2_PreRender" OnSorting="GridView2_Sorting" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="GridView2_RowCreated" >
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
          <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="ActivityDate" SortExpression="ActivityDate" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Outcome" HeaderText="Outcome" SortExpression="Outcome" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File" ShowHeader="False"> <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImportedFilename") %>'
                CommandName="Download" Text='<%# Eval("ImportedFilename") %>'>
                </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Names="Arial" />
          <PagerStyle  ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderStyle="None" />
          <RowStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black"/>
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
      </asp:GridView>

       </td>          
        </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
          <td style ="color: Black ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Page Number:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageNumbers1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlPageNumbers_SelectedIndexChanged1"></asp:DropDownList></td>          
           </tr>
      </table>
      <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllImportLogs" TypeName="demo.ImportLogAccessLayer">
          <SelectParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="pageIndex" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="pageSize" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="sortDirection" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="totalRows" Type="Int32" />
          </SelectParameters>
      </asp:ObjectDataSource>

  </div>
  <div id="tab7">

  </div>
  <div id="tab8">
   </div>
```

```
  function resetTabs() {
      $("#content > div").hide(); //Hide all content
      $("#tabs a").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's     

  }

  var myUrl = window.location.href; //get URL
  var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf("#")); // For localhost/tabs.html#tab2, myUrlTab = #tab2     
  var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0, 4); // For the above example, myUrlTabName = #tab


Sys.Application.add_Load(tabs);
      (function tabs() {
      $("#content > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
      $("#tabs li:first a").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
      $("#content > div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

      $("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($(this).attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
              return
          }
          else {
              resetTabs();
              $(this).attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
              $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
          }
      });

      for (i = 1; i <= $("#tabs li").length; i++) {
          if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
              resetTabs();
              $("a[name='" + myUrlTab + "']").attr("id", "current"); // Activate url tab
              $(myUrlTab).fadeIn(); // Show url tab content        
          }
      }
  })()
```

When ever I try to use dropdown in tab 6, It resets to tab 1. The dropdown list works fine, but i have to again click tab 6 to look at the result. I tried to fix it several ways, it did not work. Any help would be appreciated to prevent the tabs from getting resetting.

Comment: You page is performing a postback on the selection.  Which means its refreshing and starting over again in its layout so you lose your selected tab. If you want to maintain your tab selection through postback I would create a hidden field and when a tab is selected maintain its ID in the hidden field and on page load or post back have your Jquery select its tab based off that when the page is loaded, or if its an initial load default to tab 1 if the field is empty and start setting it as tabs are selected.  Either that or make your drop down selection Ajax enabled so the page is not refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Jquery code inside  `Sys.Application.add_load( //your code here)` on `DOM` ready

**EDIT 2 (Removed Reset Tabs function and calling directly in add_load**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
           $("#content > div").hide(); //Hide all content
         $("#tabs a").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's     

                $("#content > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
                $("#tabs li:first a").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
                $("#content > div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

                $("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ($(this).attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        resetTabs();
                        $(this).attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
                        $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
                    }
                });

                for (i = 1; i <= $("#tabs li").length; i++) {
                    if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
                        resetTabs();
                        $("a[name='" + myUrlTab + "']").attr("id", "current"); // Activate url tab
                        $(myUrlTab).fadeIn(); // Show url tab content        
                    }
                }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this one. But it isnt working. Can you provide more info like which part of code. Thanks

Comment: I just edited the code as you suggested. you can see the change in the jquery section of the code.

Comment: @Raags Some extent means ??

Comment: if possible add `resetTabs()` function to `add_load`

Comment: Ok. I will try that.The dropdown list is working fine, but i lost the functionality of the tabs. The content of all the tabs is showing on one page.

Comment: @Raags you mean related to `resetTabs` ?

Comment: Yes, I think resetTabs might be an issue

Comment: Are you calling it some where or is it one time ?

Comment: then add that to `load`

Comment: Webruster - The method you suggested worked. Thank you very much. I was also able to solve the same issue with "Update Panel".

Answer (score 0):

When you select value from dropdown, your page PostBack (Most probably it is requirement). Now this post back takes you to server side, and the core issue is that you are not telling server that you are on 6th tab.

Pass the tab id to server so that when postback returns, it will check tab Id and will set the same tab enabled.

However if you are not re-loading data then disable reloading which is actual cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the method suggested by @Webruster. I was also able to solve the issue by using "Update Panel". Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: if it helped you plz accept it as answer.. it might usefull for some other users